# Azure SDK is installed but Visual Studio 2012 doesn't see it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure, visual-studio-2012

Under cloud I only see "Get Windows Azure SDK for .NET" yet I know it's installed. The installer sees it.

I should mention I have Visual Studio 2010 installed along size 2012. 2010 has all the project types and works great.

Answer (score 20):

Open Programs and Features, locate the 'Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx' (where xx is the version of Visual Studio you are experiencing the issue with)

Right click and choose Repair.

Once the repair is complete, re-open Visual Studio, search installed templates for 'Cloud' and the 'Windows Azure Cloud Service' project should appear, confirming that the issue is resolved.

Comment: This just happened to me after a windows update (Sept 15, 2013). Something about an incompatible 'CctSharedPackage'. The above solution worked for me.

Comment: +1 This has just saved me hours of work. I have found that this happens regardless of Win OS version, but it has just happened on this mornings Windows 8 update.

Comment: It was not working for me .. But keep repairing all the 8 setups that were installed. and it will surely work. I did all and finally the web developers .. and it worked. !!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  Rebooted, still couldn't get it to recognize the Azure SDK 2.1 for VS 2012.
When I right-clicked, I only had the options to Uninstall or Change.  I chose Uninstall, and another windows popped up asking if I wanted to repair.  I chose Repair and then finally Windows Azure Cloud Service appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue few days ago. Both, VS10 and VS12 installed on Win 7 machine. And VC12 didn't see azure so I followed steps from VS12 and installed it again and then it still didn't work.

However, after VS12 and system restart it actually worked.

Comment: I've re-installed the SDK myself hoping it will work and I've done a system restart as well. Neither have been successful for me.|

Short of reformatting and re-installing only Visual Studio 2012 and all the SDKs will I be able to get this to work (I think). This isn't feasible since I maintain older projects as well.

I've had issues with Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 and similar things in the past.

Comment: Have you tried opening Azure project with VS12? This might help because VS will then try to check sort of dependencies I guess.

Comment: I found the answer. I had to completely remove the SDK and reinstall it from scratch. This seemed to fix it.

Comment: I have tried repair, uninstall, re-install.  Nothing seems to work.  VS2013 still doesn't recognize Azure SDK.  I checked I am installing the right version 2.3 for VS2013